# How do I preserve invalid data in my view if the controller rejects it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I have a model with a date attribute (named “dob”, whicih maps to a PostGres table column that has type "date").  I have the following text input on the page that allows the user to enter this information

```
   <%= f.text_field :dob, :value => (f.object.dob.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if f.object.dob), :size => "20", :class => 'textField', placeholder: 'MM/DD/YYYY' %>
  <% if @user.errors[:dob] %><%= @user.errors[:dob] %><% end %>
```

On the controller side, I have this logic for handling the input

```
  def update
    @user = current_user
    begin
      @user.dob = Date.strptime(params[:user][:dob], '%m/%d/%Y')
    rescue ArgumentError => ex
      @user.errors.add(:dob, 'The birth date is not in the right format.')
    end
    if !@user.errors.any? && @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      last_page_visited = session[:last_page_visited]
      if !last_page_visited.nil?
        session.delete(:last_page_visited)
      else
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      end
      redirect_to !last_page_visited.nil? ? last_page_visited : url_for(:controller => 'races', :action => 'index') and return
    else
      @country_selected = !@user.address.nil? && !@user.address.country.nil? ? @user.address.country : Country.cached_find_by_iso('US')
      @states = @country_selected.states.sort_by {|obj| obj.name}
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

However, the problem is, when someone enters an invalid input (e.g. “01-02/2012”, they are returned to the page but the data they entered is no longer there.  How do I preserve the incorrect data they entered in the view?

Answer (score 1):

```
     else
        @country_selected = !@user.address.nil? && 
        ...
        @user.dob = params[:user][:dob]
```

Since it's just a text field I'm thinking this should work. 
However,  a few questions: Are you submitting the form through ajax? if not, consider doing so. And how about validating the date on the front end side of your code? You should at the very least strive to take the validation out of the Rails controller and putting it in the User model. It's considered the 'Rails way' to move validation logic to the model, not the controller http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: No, I'm not submitting through AJAX.  I'm fine to change to the "Rails way" and add the validation rules you speak of, just let me know what those are and what the equivalent controller code should be.

Comment: Anyway, adding "@user.dob = params[:user][:dob]" doesn't work anyway (the resuting text field in the view is blank).